# how to make bottom recycler views as google maps which is used to highlight the location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, oop

I need a design like which is used in GoogleMaps with bottom recycler view  and when we change the item in recycler view by sliding horizontally it should show the location of that particular item pls I have searched many things but I didn't get the solution pls help me or give me the concept or resources

this is the link of picture :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGOA2.jpg

Comment: It's a RecyclerView or you can also use ViewPager2 (which is under the hood is a RecyclerView), then, find the current visible item using the LayoutManager of the RV, get Lat long of the selected location from the database/data model or an array, whatever you're using, and focus the map on that marker, it's very easy actually.

Comment: how could we use viewpager2 ?

Comment: should I implement  viewpager2 inside of recycler view?

Comment: Hey Ramanadha, it may seem confusing initiallly but it's not a single task, it's a series of task to achieve the output you want. So, you can choose either RV or VP, suppose we chose RV, next set-up an adapter with the data list, connect the adapter to the RecyclerView, set-up the manager of the RecyclerView with Horizontal orientation, next, set-up a scroll listener to the RecyclerView to listen to the item change, next, on this item change, find the current visible item using the manager and move the map accordingly. Follow this, step by step, search anything you get stuck on. This is it.

Comment: Lalit Fauzdar  sir, implementing of view pager2 is completed .   as we use onScrolllistener for recyclerview  anything there for view pager2?

Comment: Check [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/look-deep-into-viewpager2-13eb8e06e419), it will solve your problem, use `OnPageChangeCallback` from it.